# Clearing textfield blackberry

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How do I clear the `TextField` in blackberry? Here's the qml:

```js
Container {
                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
                        leftPadding: 75
                        rightPadding: leftPadding
                        bottomPadding: 40

                    TextField {
                        id: tfComment
                        hintText: qsTr("add comment")
                        inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Text
                        input {
                            submitKey: SubmitKey.Submit
                            onSubmitted: {
                                cppObj.onCommentSubmitClicked(tfComment.text, "");
                                lComment.text = tfComment.text;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

Container {
                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
                        bottomPadding: 200
                        leftPadding: 20
                        rightPadding: leftPadding

                       Label {
                           id: lComment
                           verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
                           horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                           text: cppObj.desc
                       }
                    }
```

I want to clear the data entered to the `TextField` so there'll be room for me to comment another. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`textField->resetText()`

The documentation is here:

http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__textfield.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside the `onSubmitted` handler:

```
tfComment.Text = ""
```